# How do I solve the "a Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'" error?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript with strict compiler options which I really like. But when I have a for loop I get the following error `a Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`. I changed `let i` to `let i:number` shouldn't that fix it?

Here is the

[image]

Comment: what do you see if you `console.log(typeof keys[i])` inside the loop?

Comment: Welcome! You may get better assistance if posting the code in your post instead of a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with your `i` variable.
`event.touches`'s type is TouchList, this is how it looks:

```
interface TouchList {
    readonly length: number;
    item(index: number): Touch | null;
    [index: number]: Touch;
}
```

The index has to be a number yet Object.keys returns a `string[]` and this is why you have a type mismatch.

You need to cast the string to number. You can do something as simple as `Number(keys[i])` but there are at least two keys (length & item) that are not numbers so I recommend that you check that your casting returns an actual number first and only then push it to `this.touches`

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the value of `keys[i]`:

```
this.touches.push(event.touches[(keys[i] as number)])
```

Or if you expect it to be string then `(keys[i] as string)`

Comment: Well keys[i] is a string. i is a number. But i think this doesn't need a cast and that casting is a sign of code smell.

Comment: what do you see if you `console.log(typeof keys[i])` inside the loop?

Comment: "that casting is a sign of code smell". You may be forced to use it specially if you are using data that are not under your control. It's bad only if you cast data that you already strongly typed in the first place.